# Passing value input by user to another html page using javascript and redirect using javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html page that ask user to input the following

1. username and password click submit to redirect to load.html
2. no input, but click on generate ID, automatically redirect to load.html
3. input unique id, and redirect to load.html

However, I know I need to store the either username and password, or the unique id. I have tried the following

```
var user = document.getElementById("username");
var password = document.getElementById("password");
localStorage.user = user;
localStorage.password = password;
```

and I try to use that in load.html through the following

```
var user = localStorage.user;
```

but I have no idea how to get the user input using the variable. In addition is there a way I can redirect to another web page using a function rather than form?

Thanks in advance

```
function connector_id()
{
    var id_ =document.getElementById("id")
    id_.innerHTML=Math.floor((Math.random()*100000000)+100000000);
    return id_;
}

var user = document.getElementById("username");
var password;
localStorage.user = user;
localStorage.password = password;



</script>


<form action = "load.html" method = "post">
    Username: <input type = "text" name = "username" id="username"/>
    <br />
    Password: <input type = "password" name = "pass" />
    <br />
    <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
</form>


<p id ="id"></p>

<button onclick="connector_id()">generate</button>
</p>

<form action = "load.html" method = "post">
    ID: <input type = "text" name = "username" />
    <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You should be using PHP for this.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of stuff you have to use a server-side language (PHP, ASP, etc.) as you can pass variables thru files and so forth.

Doing this with HTML/JS only is going to get you in trouble as you are basically giving the user, pass and id to anyone openly.

Have a look here: [PHP Codecademy.com](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/php)

Comment: Is php compatible with node.js? I am planning to create the front end that can integrate with node.js from another group. Also, doesn't this make javascript kind of redundant, as not being able to pass variable around securely limits the function of javascript?

Comment: Yes of course, have a look here: [PHP & NodeJS](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/nodejs-php-programmers-1-event)